# Django tutorial - can't connect to the page after modifying a template

Tags: python, django, templates

From the [Django tutorial part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/):

> Create a templates directory in your project directory. Open your
>   settings file (`mysite/settings.py`, remember) and add a
>   `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting:
>
> ```
> TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
> ```

So I created a folder called `'templates'` in `mysite` folder, and copied the TEMPLATE_DIR settings above to `settings.py` in a pretty much random place. Next step:

> Now create a directory called admin inside templates, and copy the
>   template `admin/base_site.html` from within the default Django admin
>   template directory in the source code of Django itself
>   (`django/contrib/admin/templates`) into that directory.

I followed the instructions - I created another folder called `admin` inside my templates folder, and copied a file called `base_site.html` from `django/contrib/admin/templates` into my new admin folder.

But when I tried to reopen my website again it said: *"Chrome couldn't connect to 127.0.0.1:8000"*. So I reversed all the changes (deleted the `TEMPLATE_DIR` configuration from `settings.py` and the templates folder), but my page still won't open.

Any ideas what could've happened? (I'd hate to go through the tutorial from the beginning)

Comment: Do you see any errors in the server? (share the last 4 lines in the window where you ran the `python manage.py runserver` command, after you do a bad request). If it isn't running - well, that's your problem right there

Answer (score 0):

If your browser says it cannot connect to the server, then the web server is not responding. Are you sure you are still running the web server? ;)

If there had been errors in your setup, you would have recieved a 500 server error, or the Django debug template with the stacktrace that occured.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's embarrassing. I don't really know what a server is so I didn't pay much attention to `python manage.py runserver`. Now I know that you have to run the server with this command before you open 127.0.0.1:8000 in a browser. (This *was* covered in the tutorial but way back..)
Thanks yuvi!

Comment: In a very simple sense, a "server" is something that "serves" your site on the web. Your django project is the kitchen, `runserver` is the waiter/waitress, and your browser is the customer.

Comment: This might be a dumb question but here it goes.. servers are physical things that you generally have to pay for to use. So how come I can just give this server commands to 'serve' my content to a browser? In other words: if I want to create a website I have to pay, here I don't. Why?

Comment: There's good information on `runserver` [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) that I highly recommend you read. Quite simply, `runserver` is meant for development, and can't handle the requirements needed to serve a site to multiple users all over the world. If you want to create a website using django, you don't need a server to develop. However, if you want to deploy it to the world, you'll need to put your django application on a server (usually paid). At this point, you won't be using `runserver` to make the site available.